# Using variable as array index

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array of elements that are grouped by months, for example:

```
Array
(
    [2013-01] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Project] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [created] => 2013-04-08 01:00:56
                            [modified] => 2013-04-08 01:01:40
                            [vId] => 7
                        )
                )
        )

    [2013-04] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Project] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [created] => 2013-04-08 01:00:56
                            [modified] => 2013-04-08 01:01:40
                            [refimg] => uploads/smallRef.png
                        )
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Project] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [created] => 2013-04-08 01:00:56
                            [modified] => 2013-04-08 01:01:40
                        )
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [Project] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [created] => 2013-04-08 01:00:56
                            [modified] => 2013-04-08 01:01:40
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Now I want to loop through months, and for each month I want to perform a count on the array for the specific month:

```
$currMonth = date('Y-m-d');
while (strtotime($currMonth) >= strtotime($firstMonth)) {
    $curM = date('Y-m', strtotime($currMonth));
    count($grouparr[$curM]);
    $currMonth = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($currMonth)));
}
```

This does not seem to work. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

If I enter the date manually everything works fine, for example if I replace this in the code above:

```
count($grouparr["2013-01");
```

I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: There is no syntax error in this code?

Comment: There is not even the `<` character in the code

Comment: you got a line number for that error? I don't even see a `<` in the code you posted...

Comment: "I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong" - If you do not know I expect that I will not know what you are doing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($yourarray as $month) {
 echo sizeof($month);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($grouparr as $month => $values) {

    echo "$month: " . count($values) . "<br />";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, don't use the strtotime() function if you can help it.  I don't know exactly what your end result may be, but let me offer a couple alternatives when iterating through an array like this.

First, if you just want to loop through the array...

```
foreach ($grouparr as $key => $val) {
    list($year, $month) = explode("-", $key, 2);
    printf("%s, %s has %s records",
        $month,
        $year,
        is_array($val) ? count($val) : 0
    );
}
```

Or maybe you want to go through the past 12 months...

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    //Use this timestamp for all your date calculations
    $mytime = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n") - $i, 1, date("Y"));

    if (array_key_exists( date("Y-m", $mytime), $grouparr)) {
        printf("%s, %s has %s records",
            date("F", $mytime),
            date("Y", $mytime),
            is_array($grouparr[date("Y-m", $mytime)]) ? count(date("Y-m", $mytime)) : 0
        );
    }
}
```

These code samples can be a lot simpler, but...